# One column of data that needs splitting in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
0 movie*
1 star wars
2 the godfather
3 zombieland
4 book*
5 romeo and juliet
6 harry potter
7 tv series*
8 breaking bad
9 game of thrones
...
```

so categories followed by items in that category, followed by other categories, all in one column.
assume data like this goes on for a while with many different categories.

what i then want is to frame the data as:

```
  type        name

0 movie*      star wars   
1 movie*      godfather
2 movie*      zombieland
3 book*       romeo and juliet
4 book*       harry potter
5 tv series*  breaking bad
6 tv series*  game of thrones
...
```

i've gotten to achieving a boolean mask with .endswith('*') but don't know how to incorporate this into a new data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
               name
0            movie*
1         star wars
2     the godfather
3        zombieland
4             book*
5  romeo and juliet
6      harry potter
7        tv series*
8      breaking bad
9   game of thrones
```

First create new column for first position by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) for missing values if no match and forward filling non missing values, then filter out same values in both columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and last remove `*` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'type', df['name'].where(df['name'].str.endswith('*')).ffill())
df = df[df['type'].ne(df['name'])].copy()
df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip('*')
print (df)
        type              name
1      movie         star wars
2      movie     the godfather
3      movie        zombieland
5       book  romeo and juliet
6       book      harry potter
8  tv series      breaking bad
9  tv series   game of thrones
```